# Finding acronyms with >=1 letters at the start of each consecutive word

Tags: python, recursion

**Problem**

I'm seeking a clean and efficient way to determine whether one string is an initialism/acronym of another.

Example: **IBM** => **I**nternational **B**usiness **M**achines

**However**, a key condition for my use case is that an initialism might be constructed using *more than one* letter from each consecutive word.

Example: **ANEXAIST** = **An** **Exa**mple **Is** **T**his

**Working solution**

My solution works, though only returns a single answer (even when multiple might exist - this is fine for my use case). I wonder if there's a cleaner and more efficient implementation?

```
s1 = 'anexithi'
s2 = 'an example is this'

def recursive_split(s1, s2, mapping=[]):
    for s1_sub in [s1[:i] for i in range(4)]:
        if s1_sub!='' and s1_sub == s2[:len(s1_sub)]:
            mapping_ = mapping + [(s1_sub, s2.split()[0])]
            if s1_sub == s1:
                return mapping_
            rec = recursive_split(s1[len(s1_sub):], ' '.join(s2.split()[1:]), mapping_)
            if rec is not None:
                return rec

recursive_split(s1, s2)
```

**Output**

```
[('an', 'an'), ('ex', 'example'), ('i', 'is'), ('thi', 'this')]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Correctness

- Your code allows partial acronyms which doesn't seem right. "I'm seeking a clean and efficient way to determine whether one string is an initialism/acronym of another."

  ```
  recursive_split('aei', 'an example is this')
  # [('a', 'an'), ('e', 'example'), ('i', 'is')]
  ```

## Performance 1

1. A list comprehension being fed into a for loop is not idiomatic. It would be better if you move the expression into the for's expression.

   ```py
   for i in range(4):
       s1_sub = s1[:i]
   ```
2. It should be clear if `len(s1_sub) != i` then `s1_sub == s2[:len(s1_sub)]` is going to call the body multiple times with the same values. To address this wastage we can bound the for loop.

   ```py
   for i in range(min(4, 1 + len(s2))):
   ```
3. Rather than `s1_sub!=''` we can start the range at 1.

   ```py
   for i in range(1, min(4, 1 + len(s2))):
   ```
4. If `len(s1) < len(s2)` then we are wasting iterations of the for loop when we could just adjust the range.

   ```py
   for i in range(1, min(4, 1 + len(s1), 1 + len(s2))):
   ```
5. If `s1[:i] != s2[:i]` then i+1 will always be false too. You should instead `break` if this is ever false.

   ```py
   for i in range(1, min(4, 1 + len(s1), 1 + len(s2))):
       s1_sub = s1[:i]
       if s1_sub != s2[:i]:
           break
       # do stuff
   ```
6. We don't need to slice `s1` and `s2` to compare the values. We can just index. This makes the range a little simpler.

   ```py
   for i in range(min(3, len(s1), len(s2))):
       if s1[i] != s2[i]:
           break
       s1_sub = s1[:1 + i]
   ```

```py
def recursive_split(s1, s2, mapping=[]):
    for i in range(min(3, len(s1), len(s2))):
        if s1[i] != s2[i]:
            break
        s1_sub = s1[:1 + i]
        mapping_ = mapping + [(s1_sub, s2.split()[0])]
        if s1_sub == s1:
            return mapping_
        rec = inner(s1[len(s1_sub):], ' '.join(s2.split()[1:]), mapping_)
        if rec is not None:
            return rec
```

## Clean code

Many of the changes above have increased the readability of your code.

- The names `s1` and `s2` aren't very descriptive.

## Performance 2

These are some more advanced performance changes. Depending on the person the decreased readability may not outweigh the performance gains.

7. Rather than using `mapping=[]` you can use a closure and pass a fresh mapping.

   ```py
   def recursive_split(s1, s2):
       def inner(s1, s2, mapping):
           for i in range(min(3, len(s1), len(s2))):
               if s1[i] != s2[i]:
                   break
               s1_sub = s1[:1 + i]
               mapping_ = mapping + [(s1_sub, s2.split()[0])]
               if s1_sub == s1:
                   return mapping_
               rec = inner(s1[len(s1_sub):], ' '.join(s2.split()[1:]), mapping_)
               if rec is not None:
                   return rec
       return inner(s1, s2, [])
   ```
8. Constantly calling `s2.split()` and `' '.join(s2.split()[1:])` are very wasteful. Instead you could call `str.split` *once* and just work with the split list.

   ```py
   def recursive_split(s1, s2):
       def inner(s1, s2_index, mapping):
           try:
               s2 = s2s[s2_index]
           except IndexError:
               return None
           for i in range(1, min(4, 1 + len(s1), 1 + len(s2))):
               s1_sub = s1[:i]
               if s1_sub != s2[:i]:
                   break
               mapping_ = mapping + [(s1_sub, s2s[s2_index])]
               if s1_sub == s1:
                   return mapping_
               rec = inner(s1[len(s1_sub):], s2_index + 1, mapping_)
               if rec is not None:
                   return rec
       s2s = s2.split()
       return inner(s1, 0, [])
   ```
9. We don't need to add `s2s[s2_index]` to `mapping_` because `s2_index` only ever increases by 1 each time so we can do that outside of `inner`.

   ```py
   mapping_ = mapping + [s1_sub]
   ```

   ```py
   ret = inner(s1, 0, [])
   if ret is None:
       return None
   return list(zip(ret, s2s))
   ```
10. With `mapping + [s1_sub]` will make near duplicate copy each time you recurse. We can improve the performance by mutating the mapping.

    To do this we just append to the stack where you did `mapping + [s1_sub]` and then pop after any recursion.

    ```py
    def recursive_split(s1, s2):
        def inner(s1, s2_index, mapping):
            try:
                s2 = s2s[s2_index]
            except IndexError:
                return None
            for i in range(min(3, len(s1), len(s2))):
                if s1[i] != s2[i]:
                    break
                s1_sub = s1[:1 + i]
                mapping.append(s1_sub)
                if s1_sub == s1:
                    return mapping
                else:
                    rec = inner(s1[1 + i:], s2_index + 1, mapping)
                    if rec is not None:
                        return rec
                mapping.pop()
        s2s = s2.split()
        ret = inner(s1, 0, [])
        if ret is None:
            return None
        return list(zip(ret, s2s))
    ```
11. We can do something similar to `s1`. However instead of appending and popping we can pop in the for loop and then extend after the for loop. As such we just need to reverse `s1`.

    ```py
    def recursive_split(s1, s2):
        def inner(s1, s2_index, mapping):
            try:
                s2 = s2s[s2_index]
            except IndexError:
                return None
            s1_sub = []
            for i in range(min(3, len(s1), len(s2))):
                s1_sub.append(s1.pop())
                if s1_sub[-1] != s2[i]:
                    break
                mapping.append(s1_sub)
                if not s1:
                    return mapping
                else:
                    rec = inner(s1, s2_index + 1, mapping)
                    if rec is not None:
                        return rec
                mapping.pop()
            s1.extend(s1_sub[::-1])
        s2s = s2.split()
        ret = inner(list(reversed(s1)), 0, [])
        if ret is None:
            return None
        return [
            (''.join(s1_sub), s2)
            for s1_sub, s2 in zip(ret, s2s)
        ]
    ```
12. We can use generators and a couple of tricks to reduce the line count.

    ```py
    def recursive_split(s1, s2):
        def inner(s1, s2_index, mapping):
            s2 = s2s[s2_index]
            s1_sub = []
            for i in range(min(3, len(s1), len(s2))):
                s1_sub.append(s1.pop())
                if s1_sub[-1] != s2[i]:
                    break
                mapping.append(s1_sub)
                if not s1:
                    yield mapping
                elif s2_index + 1 < len(s2s):
                    yield from inner(s1, s2_index + 1, mapping)
                mapping.pop()
            s1.extend(s1_sub[::-1])
        s2s = s2.split() or ['']
        rets = (
            [(''.join(s1_sub), s2) for s1_sub, s2 in zip(ret, s2s)]
            for ret in inner(list(reversed(s1)), 0, [])
        )
        return next(rets, None)
    ```
13. Given your examples it would be better to use a greedy search. For each letter you recurse straight away however if you went from the point we break in the `for` loop then `inner` would never return `None` on your example data.

    ```py
    def recursive_split(s1, s2):
        def inner(s1, s2_index, mapping):
            s2 = s2s[s2_index]
            s1_sub = []
            for i in range(min(3, len(s1), len(s2))):
                s1_sub.append(s1.pop())
                if s1_sub[-1] != s2[i]:
                    break
            while s1_sub:
                mapping.append(s1_sub)
                if not s1:
                    yield mapping
                elif s2_index + 1 < len(s2s):
                    yield from inner(s1, s2_index + 1, mapping)
                mapping.pop()
                s1.append(s1_sub.pop())
            # nonlocal counter
            # counter += 1
        # counter = 0
        s2s = s2.split() or ['']
        rets = (
            [(''.join(s1_sub), s2) for s1_sub, s2 in zip(ret, s2s)]
            for ret in inner(list(reversed(s1)), 0, [])
        )
        ret = next(rets, None)
        # print(counter)
        return ret
    ```

    This prints 0, if you uncomment the code, where as the previous code printed 2 because it recursed on `a` from `an` and `e` from `ex`.
14. We can remove the recursion and so we can remove the stack frames.

    In the previous example it should be clear that `mapping` is acting like a stack and we can actually get `s2_index` from it.
    Additionally we can see that the code is quite reliant now on the fact that we're mutating `s1`.

    So we can think of the code another way.

    1. Build the rest of the stack based on the state of `s1`.

       - At first this is just the same as the `for i in range(...)` loop.
       - If there are no matches, `s1_sub` is empty, then we have to start the popping process.
       - Otherwise we add the value to the stack.
       - Then if the length of the stack is the same as `s2s` then we have a value to return.
    2. Pop from the stack.

       - If we make a value in the stack empty, then we need to pop again from the stack, otherwise we'll have an infinite loop. As the builder will just build the exact same way.
       - If we pop from the entire stack, we're done.

    ```py
    def recursive_split(s1, s2):
        s1_ = list(reversed(s1))
        s2s = s2.split()
        stack = []
        while True:
            while len(stack) < len(s2s):
                s1_sub = []
                for value in s2s[len(stack)]:
                    if not s1_ or value != s1_[-1]:
                        break
                    s1_sub.append(s1_.pop())
                if not s1_sub:
                    break
                else:
                    stack.append(s1_sub)
                    if len(stack) == len(s2s):
                        return [(''.join(values), s2) for values, s2 in zip(stack, s2s)]
            for _ in range(len(stack)):
                s1_.append(stack[-1].pop())
                if stack[-1]:
                    break
                stack.pop()
            else:
                return
    ```

Comment: Amazing how we hit most of the same inefficiencies, and yet our optimized solutions are so very different.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Yeah I really focused on not having any unneeded copies / calls to \$O(n)\$ functions, so my code is... not as nice as many would normally write it :) Makes me think it looks more like C like than Python...

Comment: Brilliant answers both, it hardly seems fair to accept a single answer!

Answer (score 5):

## Inefficiencies

### Split/join

You are calling `s2.split()` a lot.  This seems wasteful.

Moreover, you are calling `' '.join(s2.split()[1:])` to get a string containing everything but the first word of `s2`.  So not only are you repeatedly splitting the string, you're also rejoining the splits.

You're doing a lot of work, just to throw it away and redo it in subsequent steps.

### range(4)

The first value of `range(4)` is `0`.  That value is used in `s1[:i]`, as `s1[:0]` which is an empty string.  After constructing a list, which always starts with this empty string, you test `if s1_sub != '' and ...`, which will never be true on the first pass.

Instead, you could use `range(1, 4)`, who's first value is `1`, avoiding the first empty string.

### len(s1_sub)

You are using `len(s1_sub)` in a few places.  This value used to be `i`, in the `for i in range(4)` statement.  Instead of building up a list of possible prefixes, and then repeatedly determining the length of those prefixes, you could simply loop over the desired lengths directly:

```py
    for i in range(1, 4):
        s1_sub = s1[:i]
        if s1_sub != '' and s1_sub == s2[:i]:
            ...
```

### Search pruning

On the first pass, you find the `'A'` from `s1` matches the first letter of the first word `an`.  So you descend into the next recursive level with `'nexithi'` and `'example is this'`.  You test `'n'` and discover that `'example is this'` doesn't start with an `'n'`.

And then you proceed to test `'ne'`, followed by `'nex'`.  Why?  If it didn't start with `'n'`, it can't start with any longer substring.  You could prune your searching!

### Limit

Why `range(4)`?  You're adding a restriction that the maximum prefix in each word is at most 3 characters.  This wasn't part of the original problem statement.

The limit should depend on the length of the remaining acronym and the remaining number of words.  At the first level, with 3 words remaining (`example is this`), at most 5 characters of `'anexithi'` could be used, leaving at least 1 each for the remaining words.  (Since the first word is only 2 letters long, we can further drop the limit to 2.)

## Reworked Code

```py
from os.path import commonprefix

def recursive_split(acronym, words):

    def recurse(acronym, words):
        head, *tail = words

        # Base case: when there are no more words
        if not tail:
            if acronym and head.startswith(acronym):
                return [(acronym, head)]
            return None

        # Determine longest allowed prefix for the first word
        limit = min(len(acronym) - len(tail), len(head))

        # Determine longest common prefix between acronym & first word 
        longest_prefix = commonprefix([acronym, head])[:limit]
        
        for length in range(1, len(longest_prefix)+1):
            mapping = recurse(acronym[length:], tail)
            if mapping is not None:
                mapping.insert(0, (acronym[:length], head))
                return mapping
            
        return None 

    words = words.split()             # Only split s2 once, at the start!

    return recurse(acronym, words)


s1 = 'anexithi'
s2 = 'an example is this'

result = recursive_split(s1, s2)
print(result)
```

Notes:

1. Although `commonprefix` is in `os.path`, it is an easy way to determine the common starting prefix of a group of strings.  Since `commonprefix(['exithi', 'example']) == 'ex'`, we use this to determine we only need to test `'e'` and `'ex'` as possible prefixes at that level.
2. When the last word is reached, `first.startswith(acronym)` is used to determine if the entire remaining `acronym` begins the last word, instead of uselessly trying each all leading substrings first.
3. We now have an outer function, which can preprocess the input (such as calling `words.split()`).
4. The outer function is no longer recursively called, so the `mapping=[]` default argument has been removed from the outer function.
5. The inner function could have still had the `mapping` argument, but it wouldn't need a default, since the outer function could explicitly provide the required "default".